# SQL distinct name pulling duplicates - already got rid of spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Edit: the solution provided by vax was successful, and should work for just about anyone facing a similar issue, as it replaces 4 different types of spacing, not just spaces. Thanks to all who provided help!

I have a table that gives industry names, but for one of the columns the distinct values have duplicates.

Here is the query I have:
`select distinct replace(final_industry,' ','') from industryNorm`

this is the results that are generated:

1. Automotive,AerospaceandDefense,Transportation,Travel,IndustrialProducts,andInfrastructure
2. Automotive,AerospaceandDefense,Transportation,Travel,IndustrialProducts,andInfrastructure
3. Communications,Media&Technology
4. ConsumerIndustriesandRetail
5. ConsumerIndustriesandRetail
6. Energy,Healthcare&ProcessIndustries
7. FinancialServices
8. FinancialServices

As you can see, many of the repeat. It seems that they still have spaces at the end, but I don't understand why, as I've run a replace function to get rid of them. I also ran a replace to put a | in the place of any space and when I do that the spaces at the end don't show up. Why is that? What can I do?

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: They may be other white space characters.

Comment: did you give it a try with:
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(final_industry,' ',''))) FROM industryNorm

Comment: Slight detour...what you have shown here is violating 1NF because you have stuffed multiple values into a single tuple. This is painful to work with. Normalizing this into a separate table is much preferable.

Comment: What version of sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you believe the problem is due to other white spaces I had a similar question that someone answered

```
select distinct replace(replace(replace(replace(
   final_industry
  ,char(9)/*tab*/,'')
  ,char(10)/*newline*/,'')
  ,char(13)/*carriage return*/,'')
  ,char(32)/*space*/,'')
from industryNorm
```

Comment: ding ding ding we have a winner! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try [RTrim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql) and [LTrim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql) instead of Replace().  [Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) will take care of other characters than just `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a very, very old bug in the replace function.

This is going to seem dumb, and that's because it is, but try putting multiple replaces in:

```
replace(replace(final_industry,' ',''), ' ','')
```

It might not help in your case but I've had times where the first replace didn't actually replace everything properly.

Here is some more explanation of why/how this happens: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/11/15/a-bug-in-microsoft-sql-servers-replace-function/

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by user Vax.

```
   select distinct replace(replace(replace(replace(
   final_industry
  ,char(9)/*tab*/,'')
  ,char(10)/*newline*/,'')
  ,char(13)/*carriage return*/,'')
  ,char(32)/*space*/,'')
  from industryNorm
```